# What is the appropriate design pattern for too many functions in one ViewController?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, video-editing

There are four buttons in the first picture. Each button will trigger a view, just like the second picture. When any button touched in the second picture, effects are added to the `playerView`. The `playerView` is one view. The view below the `playerView` is functionsView. The functionsView could trigger four `detailFunctionViews`. The question is where should the effects function code be written. Should they be in the only `viewController`? Or each `detailFunctionView` import the `viewController`, and control the player view in `viewController`, so the function code is in the `detailFunctionView`? Or just write 4 objects, just like bridges to control the `playerView` in `viewController`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: as i understand your problem, having one viewcontroller and clicking uibuttons (detailFunctionViews) would change the uiimage(playerView) is good. Having said that you business logic in viewcontroller is not good. Handling image, image processing, storage should all be a different classes. ViewContolller should only handle view and can only articulate controller objects.

Comment: You may have to use trampoline and receptionist pattern..

Comment: Take a look to this link http://khanlou.com/2014/09/8-patterns-to-help-you-destroy-massive-view-controller/ to avoid massive view controllers